# Update-AzureRmVmss command hanging and does not work when try to install custom script extension

Tags: azure, azure-vm-scale-set

I'm trying about three days to run and get result from Update-AzureRmVmss command using powershell. However after lasting 20-30 minutes of waiting, it ends with offering reconnect or quit pop-up window. Is it related with azure infrastructure? Can not azure update vmScaleSet faster?

I need to from time to time update custom script extension and apply changes to virtual machines.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Solved!
The problem was in my custom script extension. After downloading and running application there was -Wait command at the end of script. That was causing process to not finish